# Change of variable and Jacobian

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation, jacobian, change-of-variable

I am having a bit of trouble with the following question:

---

Given a region $D$ in the first quadrant bounded by $y = \sqrt{x}$, $y=2\sqrt{x}$, $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 4$, evaluate:

$$\iint_D \frac{2x^2 + y^2}{xy}dA$$

---

I first set $u = \frac{y^2}{x}$ and $v = x^2 + y^2$, then tried expressing $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$, but this made computing the Jacobian very difficult. I thus resorted to implicit differentiation to calculate the Jacobian:

\begin{align*}
u &= \frac{y^2}{x} \\
v &= x^2 + y^2 \\
\\
u \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} &= 2y \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \\
u \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} &= 2y \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \\
0 &= 2x \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + 2y \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \\
1 &= 2x \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} + 2y \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \\
\\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} &= 0 \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} &= 0 \\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} &= \frac{1}{2x + \frac{y^2}{x}} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} &= \frac{y}{4x^2 + y^2} \\
\end{align*}

I then found the Jacobian to be $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = 0$ which seems very odd considering the entire double integral would become $0$.

Is there something wrong with the implicit differentation, or my approach in general?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if this method does work in the end, but I do know you made a mistake in the first line of partial derivatives by not including product rule

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm not exactly sure I can see my mistake. Since $x$ and $y$ are expressed with respect to $u$ and $v$, wouldn't the first line be correct?

Comment: where is the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial u}x$ term? The correct line should be $$x + u \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} = 2y\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi God you're right, no clue how I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute
\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  \frac{d \left(u , v\right)}{d \left(x , y\right)} = \left|\begin{array}{cc}{u}_{x}&{u}_{y}\\
{v}_{x}&{v}_{y}
\end{array}\right| = \left|\begin{array}{cc}\displaystyle -\frac{{y}^{2}}{{x}^{2}}&\frac{2 y}{x}\\
\displaystyle  2 x&2 y
\end{array}\right| =-2 y \frac{{y}^{2}+2 {x}^{2}}{{x}^{2}}\end{equation}

Hence

\begin{equation}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  \frac{d \left(x , y\right)}{d \left(u , v\right)} = \frac{1}{\frac{d \left(u , v\right)}{d \left(x , y\right)}} = \frac{{x}^{2}}{{-2} y \left({y}^{2}+2 {x}^{2}\right)}\end{equation}

This is the jacobian that you need.